# I was allowed to enter the airport terminal by showing a boarding pass for a future flight. Should I be concerned about "security"?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tickets, airports, safety, airport-security

I take the same flight with the same company between two European neighboring countries once a month.

My boarding passes are on my smartphone, but as I book my flights months in advance, I often have 3 or 4 boarding passes on my phone.

During my previous flights, I noticed the security agents at the airport seem not to be really careful, so I decided to test them, trying to enter in my flight with the boarding pass for next month (legally bought, but valid only next month)

There are 3 security checkpoints in this airport:

- First, before cabine luggage X-ray, someone from the company ask for people to show their boarding pass. So I showed the "wrong" pass on my smartphone, she looked at it a quarter of a second and wish me a pleasant flight... *First "security" checkpoint DONE*
- Then, where your cabine luggage is X-rayed, they ask for the boarding pass, and the QR code printed on it is read by a machine. I expected to be caught at this moment but the light turns green!
  So I was allowed to enter in international area with a wrong boarding pass!
  What is checked at this moment ? Only if the QR code is valid ? If so, the date is not checked, which IMO is not normal. I'm not into IT security, but I guess it's not that hard to generate false QR codes to enter in any international area all around the world, which is a little bit freaky…
  *Second "security" checkpoint DONE*
- Finally, at the boarding gate, the light turns red when I presented the wrong card ; so I apologized, showed the right one and finally entered the flight.

This happens one month ago. Last week, I took the same flight again and showed the same boarding pass to enter in international area (which was the "good" one that time). And I was allowed again to enter, which means one can enter multiple times with the same boarding pass.

I don't know how to deal with this situation.
Should I report my experience to the airport? Should I be worried about "security"?

Or is it just normal?

Comment: Er just a guess, but admitting to authorities that you broke the law is a good way to get arrested.

Comment: Note that the QR code machine would also be fooled by a perfectly valid booking pass that doesn't belong to you (booked under another name), so it's not as if it adds any real security in the first place.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: 1) What law did he break? 2) Even if he did break any, just saying that you did is hardly sufficient evidence for anything.

Comment: Interesting. Re. should you be worried - maybe one of the airports experts here can think of some danger I've missed but it sounds like the worst someone could do based on this is get into the departures area when they don't have a flight booked and maybe buy some duty free? The baggage checks and boarding itself seem to be fine. Re. should you report it and how - see [Where can I report an airport security flaw / weakness?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48274/where-can-i-report-an-airport-security-flaw-weakness)

Comment: It's strange. I have done something similar in different conditions (arrived to the airport 8h before the flight and wanted to move to a more comfortable area) and I was denied access to the departure area. I would say it's definitely odd, but might not be a security hole. You can always buy a valid ticket and do the same with a fake name. That would be equivalent. That would grant you access.

Comment: My partner has accidentally used the wrong boarding pass before (wrong part of outward/return. The automated machines at the security check did notice that.

Comment: @CMaster the QR code in the boarding pass doesn't have any encryption, so it's trivial to fake: https://github.com/shooshx/BoardingBarcode. However the terminal can check the date, the airport code, and the ticket number.

Comment: Few months ago I was in on an international flight, and the pilots kept their door open all the time. Anyone could go in and take the plane down. I find that scarier.

Comment: A friend of mine flew from Germany to Portugal with the wrong ticket. I printed our tickets and accidentally gave him the return ticket. Nobody noticed.

Comment: It's security theater, rather than security anyway, which seems to be something you've overlooked.

Comment: @Apfelsaft: it depends on what checks the airline did; after all they had him in the computer as an expected passenger of that flight.

Comment: @user568458: for years now they have taken our water bottles and toothpaste away because of the danger of a passenger boarding a plane with too much liquid. Easily going past security with one liter of the explosive at a time sounds like a good possibility for the terrorists.

Comment: @MartinArgerami the problem is that the liquid threat was never real, it was a movie plot threat.

Comment: @Ukko: hence my point! It is one of the most stupid rules ever.

Comment: Considering TSA statistics indicate they miss ~90% or prohibited items, scanning the wrong boarding pass is hardly something to feel concerned about.

Comment: Intentionally "testing" airport security sounds like a quick and easy way to get yourself on a watchlist...

Comment: @HorusKol If they watchlist everyone who once show a wrong boarding pass, try to pass an "illegal" item in a luggage, or ring when go through a metal scanner, I guess we are (almost) all on that list... You can't know if it's intentional or not.

Comment: Interesting, at Gatwick I have take a 00:30 flight, and the gate before security wont let me in because the flight isn't until the next day, a person nearby checked the boarding pass and let me in.

Comment: I've used the same boarding pass to clear security three times.  Paper boarding pass, they marked on it so the later times they had to know.  They didn't care.  (Once to find out what was up when our plane wasn't to be found, once to get some food during the 8 hour delay.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48656/discussion-on-question-by-alexb-i-was-allowed-to-enter-the-airport-terminal-by-s).

Comment: I once missed a flight as my business trip was cancelled, non refundable so bought another one for the next day.  When I arrived at the airport the next I was told I was nearly missing my flight and allowed to go to head of queue for screening. I was surprised as I was in plenty of time - only once I got on my flight and there was someone in my seat did I realise I was using the boarding pass from the previous day!!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You didn't skip any security controls. Your luggage was checked and you went through a metal scanner. Finally, you were not allowed on board without a proper ticket. The rest is just to prevent people from accompanying their friends and family to the gate. Merely being in the terminal is not a security flaw per se, since pretty much anyone can buy a ticket and enter the secure area.

Speaking of which, I've tried the same "trick" (QR code for a different flight) at Prague Airport recently and it didn't work for the terminal access scan. However the Duty Free was happy to sell me anything without a proper check, so it was in theory possible to buy alcohol for non-EU prices.

A hacker was even able to [use a spoofed QR code](https://www.wired.com/2016/08/fake-boarding-pass-app-gets-hacker-fancy-airline-lounges/) to enter the Turkish Airlines business-class lounge, so the level of checks must be different across different airports and terminal areas.

Comment: Yep I heard about this hacker. Funny to see that there is not as much "ultra-security" as they want we believe... And yeah I didn't think about people accompanying travelers to the gate, good point

Comment: One thing to keep in mind as well is that many of these things do not have any security benefit.  They are _security theater_ done to make people feel like something is being done, but they actually do not make you safer.  This pacification of the traveling public is a valid thing because in general people are panicky and dumb in large groups.

Comment: @Ukko I'm not sure if it's really 'security theater', as the current process solves an important task: preventing travelers from bringing their friends/family to the gate. In India they go one step further and don't even allow non-passengers to enter the airport building, possibly because family sizes are much larger.

Comment: @JonathanReez What security threat does preventing families from entering the terminal protect against?  And if you thing of something like "too many people in an area is a soft target" then ask why we don't do the same thing for busy shopping centers? Using a security concern as a cover to achieve some other ends, like keeping families out, or a professional sports increasing their vending sales by blocking you from bringing in outside food or drink. That is not security, it is _security theater_, for the purpose of crowd management.

Comment: @Ukko it prevents security checks from being overloaded. If each passenger brings at least a single friend, your lines are now twice as long. Same with passport control - if passengers complain now, imagine their reactions once everything is doubled in duration :)

Comment: @JonathanReez: Not to mention, *if* there is a security-critical situation, airport ground staff now have to tend to not only with all the people who have to be in the building because they are about to travel, but also all the people who have joined the travelers for waving good-bye right at the gate.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I used to fly out of SLC all the time and we had the security screen at the gate, and it worked wonderfully.  The point is that your desire for fewer people is not a security concern, it is an after the fact rationalization for that aspect of _security theater_ that makes you feel better.  The same logic you are using would prevent any grouping of people, since if something happens it would be nice to have fewer people around.  Only two real changes have helped, better cockpit doors and passengers who will not go along with hijackers anymore.  The resit is all window dressing.

Comment: @Ukko: "and it worked wonderfully" - you have been there during evacuations? "The same logic you are using would prevent any grouping of people, since if something happens it would be nice to have fewer people around." - for what it's worth, organized groupings of people *are* limited in size and/or require pre-registration for safety reasons in various places.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper your question about evacuations is covered by the occupancy capacity and fire regulations of public buildings.  The point you are missing is that airport security is about making the flying process safer, if it does not do that it is not security.  All the rationalizations you provided have been arguments for the fire marshal to set the building's occupancy limit.  And all modern airports were designed with those limits in mind. But, there is nothing related to being an airport in all that.  And the Black Friday crowd at the mall does not have a special permit, that is nonsense.

Comment: @Ukko: Evacuation in (parts of) an airport can also happen in situations unrelated to fire, such as when someone has slipped through the security check. And of course, there are other security-related situations where having as few people as possible in a certain area is beneficial for resolving the situation. As for the "Black Friday crowd", if I understand the descriptions of the concept I am seeing online correctly, that does not exactly seem to be an organized gathering. If anyone, the stores that intentionally attract exceptionally large crowds are responsible for ensuring the safety ...

Comment: ... of their visitors by preventing overcrowding, such as by placing employees at the entrance and having customers queue up in front of the store before too many people enter at a time.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper it might just be cultural, but issues of evacuation and crowd carrying capacity are usually dictated by the fire marshal and fire code.  Even if there are other events that could trigger the need to evacuate, someone yelling "fire" is the canonical example.  I am more than happy to help you suss out the differences between _security_ and _security theater_ but aren't responses like  "Evacuation...unrelated to fire." a bit willingly obtuse? The whole point is that these are not issues specific to airport security, and so are not relevant.

Comment: @Ukko: Evacuation of an area because someone slipped through the security checkpoint seems pretty much airport-specific to me, given that where I live, barely any other public place features such checkpoints in the first place, let alone is so serious about them.

Comment: @Ukko Dumb in small groups as well!

Comment: They are not QR codes. Apparently the barcodes used for boarding passes are known as BCBP codes. But the picture in the article you link to is neither QR nor BCBP, rather it looks like a system mostly used for train tickets (which I don't know the name of).

Comment: Note that for flights to, from, and within the US, airlines cannot issue boarding passes until 24 hours before the flight. But I haven't tested if you can access the secure area the day before a flight. If I do get access, it's trivial to just walk out.

Answer (score 71):

The reason why you have to show your boarding cards at the security check is not because it is insecure to let people without boarding passes in (there is no particular reason to think people without boarding cards are more dangerous than people with boarding cards), but merely to reduce the workload of the security screens.

If people without boarding cards were allowed through security, many friends and family of departing passengers might want to accompany them to the gate, making the checkpoint lines longer for everybody and potentially requiring more security screeners to be hired.

But it is not really *security* problem to let people without boarding cards through the check, given that they (you) were subjected to the same actual security screening for dangerous items as everyone else.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason is that you're possibly entering a tax-free zone

Comment: @StephanBijzitter That is not a security problem.

Comment: Exactly, so this question can be answered as "No, because it's not about security in the first place".

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: In my experience, at most airports in Europe the airside concourse is used both by domestic, intra-EU and out-of-EU passengers, and your  boarding card must be scanned at the till in order to buy "duty-free" items. So a pre-security boarding card check is not really relevant for that.

Comment: @Henningmakholm those systems are extremely easy to cheat, which is probably why the "tax free discounts" are usually not worth wasting your money on.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Sure, but I don't think a boarding-card check at security makes them appreciably _harder_ to cheat.

Comment: @HenningMakholm well, in theory one might enter the airport one a fake boarding pass, buy duty-free alcohol and exit right out. So I guess it does make cheating a bit easier.

Comment: @JonathanReez I do assume that you must pass customs on your way out of a custom free zone. Not declaring is a criminal offense.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider on the way out you simply make use of your daily import quota :)

Comment: @StephanBijzitter That's not the reason. U.S. airports are not tax-free zones (there is no "international area" in U.S. airports,) yet boarding passes are still required to pass through security. However, this was not required until after the September 11 attacks.

Comment: Then apparently in the US it's indeed for security reason, but so far at all European airports I've been to (and that's quite many), the only reason seems to be related to money.

Answer (score 17):

If you're concerned about that minor issue, you should really look into how the USA's Transportation Security Administration (TSA) failed 95% of security tests last year. A simple Google search for "TSA failure rate" will reveal [dozens](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/29/those-aggravating-airport-lines-its-really-the-tsas-fault-founding-father.html) of [articles](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/06/01/tsa-fails-95-percent-tests-homeland-security_n_7485558.html) on how airport security is nothing but mere theater. And yet it costs that country's taxpayers roughly [US$7 billion per year](http://www.cnn.com/2015/06/05/opinions/schneier-tsa-security/).

Comment: That one made me smile, but your logic is wrong. Why should TSA pass _any_ security assessments? Security is not what they provide. TSA is a means to fool people into _believing_ they are safe, and a means to give people who won't get another job something to do. Nothing else, really. It's not like terrorists would go through controls in the first place. They'll drive a car with a trunk full of explosives through the wide open gate right onto the airfield, and hand it to their accomplice who works in baggage handling...

Answer (score 7):

An far more important reason than security concerns for having to present your boarding pass at the security line is to help channel passengers to their correct departure areas. They look at the boarding pass you present, and if it's one for the far other end of the airport direct you there rather than having you enter the wrong place and possibly hours later have to rush several kilometers to get to your actual gate.

As the vast majority of passengers won't have more than one boarding pass with them at any one time, your experience is just not one that is handled by this small extra bit of customer service.
In fact at Schiphol they have airport staff standing before the actual security lines directing you this way or that based on your boarding pass (just as they have people directing you to checkin lines based on your ticket).

Comment: If that were a decisive reason for the check, it doesn't explain why (a) the check is found even in airports with only one line of security checkpoints, nor (b) why a non-passenger cannot _accompany_ a passenger through the checkpoint even at the right place for the passenger's flight.

Comment: “Passengers only” is not rigid.  I accompanied a friend to her gate at FWA two years ago.

Comment: @WGroleau seems like a security breach to me. You'd never get past security without a boarding pass on any modern airport I've visited since 9/11 (and most less strict ones). In many places you'd not even get TO security (e.g. at Amsterdam you need to open a guarded gate with your boarding pass to get into the security line before entering the departure lounge), and in some not even inside the terminal building.

Comment: @jwenting: Actually, either TSA or the airline (I forget which) gave me a document authorizing me to accompany her.  Perhaps they were short of staff (she needed assistance).  So, it's true that you won't get in without showing _something_, but not that you "must" be a passenger.  If by Amsterdam you mean AMS, in late 2014, I don't recall having to open a gate with my boarding pass.

Comment: @WGroleau that system was only implemented at AMS in 2016 :) Took me by surprise too the first time I saw it.

Answer (score 7):

Security checks need to be updated when they fail, so it does help if individuals who notice a possible fail inform the service that runs or controls them.

I noticed that in more places the boarding pass checks are done by machines and it is more likely for those to catch the wrong dates if the software is instructed to do so.
I think it is good to warn the security firms and the airports in case they have overlooked the option of using a still to come boarding pass. There are not that many companies that allow you to check in more than 30 hours ahead of time and it is likely that the date is not part of the checks now because of that. Most people will not have boarding passes for more than the current and the next day.

But on the other hand, I do not think your security was ever less than acceptable, if not 100%. It is not hard to buy an international ticket and get a boarding pass for any given day and unless you are suspected of being or becoming a terrorist nobody will worry about you having one.
The security person at the first checkpoint has no reason to be suspicious of people using a future time boarding pass. And you were not allowed on the flight with the wrong pass, so no harm done there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Good security checks depend very much on detecting suspicious behaviour. If you have a valid boarding pass and by mistake go to the wrong gate, you will be behaving like someone who has a valid boarding pass and raise no suspicious. If you have a forged boarding pass and intentionally go to a gate where you shouldn't be, you may very will raise suspicion and be stopped. You can't judge security by their inability to stop innocent travellers that made some mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, boarding pass "checks" at security are usually not really there for security reasons. It's completely meaningless without also checking associated photo ID, and that's done at the gate.

As already stated by others, reasons for the "check" include avoiding non-passengers entering the secure area and making sure you enter the right terminal. When checked manually, the person doing the checks is usually concentrated on checking a single item on each boarding pass, usually the terminal or gate area, or the airline, nothing more.

Another reason for the "check" (but that usually involves a scan at each point, so it's probably not the case here) is to count waiting times. Someone will scan your boarding pass when you enter the queue, someone else will scan it once you actually get to the scanner. And the end result is displayed on pretty little screens.

Comment: In my most recent flights, I noticed that the persons letting me into the security screen physically put check marks on three items on the boarding pass.  Two of these were US TSA; the others were mainland China.  All of them compared my passport photo to my face.  At the actual boarding gate, the Chinese did not look at my passport.  The Chinese, both mainland and Taiwan, also took a face photo at immigration screening on arrival.